# A free abelian group and a free group quotient by its commutator group

Tags: free-groups, free-abelian-group

My definitions:
A free abelian group is an abelian group which has a basis.
(Here, a basis of a free abelian group is a subset of the group which generates it and they are $\mathbb{Z}$-independent)

My question:
A free abelian group is not free unless it is cyclic but we still call it 'free' because, i guess,
a free abelian group $G$ has only relation $ab=ba$ for all $a,b \in G$.

To justify my guess,  i've tried to prove the following:
Let $F$ be a group on a set $X$ and $F'=\langle aba^{-1}b^{-1} \mid a,b \in F \rangle$ be the commutator group of $F$. 
Then the quotient group ${F}/{F'}$ is a free abelian group so it has a basis.

In this case, how can i find a basis of $F/F'$?

Comment: An element of $F/F'$ is a monomial of words in $X$, so $X$ is a basis, and $F/F'\simeq \mathbb{Z}^X$.

Comment: how can i show X (in F/F') is $\mathbb{Z}$ - linearly indepentdent?

Comment: If $(F:C \to D) \dashv (G:D \to C)$ and $(H:D \to E) \dashv (K:E \to D)$, then $(H \circ F:C \to E) \dashv (G \circ K:E \to C)$. Now, let $C$, $D$, and $E$ be the categories of sets, groups, and abelian groups respectively, and $F$, $G$, $H$, and $K$, be the free group, forgetful, abelianization, and inclusion functors respectively.

Comment: Geoffrey, while your answer is obviously correct, it probably offers little to no insight to OP, considering the level of their question and their post history.

Comment: @sijinyeom you want to show that for any $g_i \in F/F'$, $\sum a_ig_i = 0 \implies a_i = 0$ for all $i$. I'm going to denote by $\tilde{g}_i$ a preimage of $g_i$ in $F$. Then note that $\Pi \tilde{g}_i^{a_i}$ is a preimage of $\sum a_i g_i$. What can you deduce from this?